# jQuery: Placing Random Elements

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for assistance in coding a jquery to randomly place 100  elements in the page. It should look like this when complete:
[image: random images]

I have the html so far and I can show 100 divs just not randomly placed. What am I missing here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery: Placing Random Elements</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        div {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: lightblue;
            opacity: .5;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px gray;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var div = $('#div');
    var makeDiv = function(){

        var $newdiv;
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            $newdiv = $('<div id="div"></div>').addClass('div');
            $('body').append($newdiv);
        }

    }; makeDiv();

});

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes this wont show up the divs in different positions, You have to calculate different positions within a certain bound while appending each of those elements. Try to use `Math.rnd`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing top and left positioning in your code, it have to be some random...

Here is a little improved code:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/B4xF9/2/

```
<head>
    <title>jQuery: Placing Random Elements</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        div {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: lightblue;
            opacity: .5;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px gray;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
$(function() {
    var maxLeft = parseInt($(window).width() - 100,10);
    var maxTop = parseInt($(window).height() - 100,10);
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        html += '<div id="div" style="top:'+getRandomInt(0,maxTop)+'px;left:'+getRandomInt(0,maxLeft)+'px" class="div"></div>';
    }
    $('body').append(html);
});


</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: generating a large html string and appending it once will work faster, changed for better performance... other way JS will have to append 100 times, and select body for that 100 times etc... do it once.

Comment: While using `parseInt` always define the `radix` parameter.